# Converting To Using Unobtrusive JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a desire to understand how to better structure my JavaScript efforts on a current MVC project and I was wondering if someone would be able to help illustrate a specific example for me from a scenario I have in my application.

Whilst I have a lot of desktop development experience and a fair amount of web development experience I have only ever dabbled with JavaScript in comparison and feel I have a LOT of room for improvement in both understanding and proficiency.  Specifically around how to make the best use of the W3C DOM standard.

I have a simple form on my site that posts some string data, a boolean and a date to an action method, the signature of this method is:

**MVC Controller Signature**

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void PostNewEntry(string text, string localUsersDateTime, bool isPublic)
```

I have the following defined as part of the forms html attributes:

**Inline JavaScript Function Call**

```
new { @name = "createentry", @onsubmit = "setLocalDateTime(this.localUsersDateTime);" }
```

The localUsersDateTime is a hidden input element on the form that on submission of the form executes a small JavaScript function (stored in a separate .js file, not inline) that makes use of [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to set the users local date and time before the form data is sent to back to the web site.  The setLocalDateTime function looks like:

**JavaScript Function (MyScripts.js)**

```
function setLocalDateTime(obj) {
    obj.value = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
}
```

I have two questions about this scenario really:

How to turn this into truly unobtrusive JavaScript?

How to actually degrade gracefully and still get the users local datetime in the absence of any Javascript?

I've noticed that on site like Facebook if you turn off JavaScript a fair amount of the site simply isn't even offered (Chat, Newsfeed updates) whereas in my scenario not getting the users local datetime simply isn't an option.  It's fundamental to the correct operation of this particular situation in my web site.

Comment: Graceful degradation and unobtrusive JavaScript are two very important but very different techniques. Maybe split the second part into its own question?

Comment: This is true, they are very different but it will help me and probably others if these are kept together in a full example of a specific scenario, Thanks Rick.